# AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR return values

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

How do I return the values of multiple AsyncTask into a list without using `get()`?

I'm currently doing this but I know it's not right.

```
for (int i=0; i != mediaList.size(); i++){
    UploadImage uploadImage = new UploadImage(this,
        new File(FileChooser.getPath(this, mediaList.get(i).uri)));
    String x = uploadImage.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR).get();
    mediaResult.add(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I return the values of multiple AsyncTask into a list without using get()?

You don't. `AsyncTask` is asynchronous, doing its work on a background thread.

Instead, rewrite `UploadImage` to take the entire set of files, have it process all of them, and use the results in `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a countdown latch with a counter of how many asyncs you have
Then wait for it to hit 0

```
CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(3);
Async1.oncomplete - > cdl.countDown();
Async2.oncomplete - > cdl.countDown();
Async3.oncomplete - > cdl.countDown();
cdl.await
```

Comment: This doesn't return the values of each async though, it just waits for all to be completed. Removing `get()` from my code and adding the `CountDownLatch` is all this does.

Comment: You should be able to do your return after the await.